# Research on the performance of listed subsidiaries

Tags: equities, research, performance

Some countries (India, Pakistan, Nigeria, among others) seem to force multinational corporations that do business there to list the local operation on the national stock exchange and to let public shareholders own a minority of it. E.g. there is a Nestle Nigeria, Nestle Pakistan, etc. - Nestle owns a majority or a large stake in these companies but they don't seem to be allowed to own 100%.

Is there any research on the performance of such listed subsidiaries? On the one hand, these subsidiaries might do better than truly local businesses because of the support from a big corporation; on the other hand, said corporation might not treat minority shareholders fairly.